# Prepare Docker container for worst-case rescue via shell or exec

Tags: apache, docker

I am preparing a docker container running apache in foreground via Dockerfile:

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

I build it, run it, and when i start it i have apache in foreground and can control it via

```
docker exec mycontainer dosomething
```

But if i somehow mess it up, for example by placing a corrupt apache config or ssl cert, and the apache does not start anymore because of errors. That means the whole container won't start anymore and i can not use `docker exec` to repair it.

So what i am looking for is a way to have apache running in foreground, use `docker exec` as long as everything is fine, but if apache has startup problems i want to start up the container into bin/bash instead of apache foreground mode.

Is there a way to accomplish that? How can i ensure that i do not get locked out of the container because of apache startup problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> but if apache has startup problems i want to start up the container into bin/bash instead of apache foreground mode

Yes, [any parameter passed to `docker run` would override the `CMD` ones](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cmd-default-command-or-options):

```
docker run -it <yourApacheImage> bash

$ docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

> This command is optional because the person who created the `IMAGE` may have already provided a default `COMMAND` using the Dockerfile `CMD` instruction.
>   As the operator (the person running a container from the image), you can override that `CMD` instruction just by specifying a new `COMMAND`.
>
> How can i ensure that I do not get locked out of the container because of Apache startup problem?

You can exactly: it is failed to start, it will be in "Exited" mode, and you will have to remove that container.
Then you start a new one with a bash session, and in that bash, try to start again the Apache: when it fails again, you are in the container and can look at the logs.

Comment: @kroiz True, thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.